# Calculation of percentage

Tags: php, mysqli, sum, percentage

I want to do a calculation on percentage of student attendance of each students, and it will display each attendance percentage that belongs to each of the students. Below is my code:

```
<tbody>
            <?php
            $counter = 1;

            // SUM( `studatt_endtime` - `studatt_starttime`)= total absent contact hour
            // (course_contacthour * course_contactx_perWeek * 14)= total contact hour in a week
            // 14 is the total week in one semester
            $data = "SELECT *,
                        ( SELECT (SUM( `studatt_endtime` - `studatt_starttime`)/(`course_contacthour` * `course_contactx_perWeek` * 14)) FROM `studentattendance` WHERE `studAtt_status`= '0' ) AS 'sum'
                        FROM `student` s
                        INNER JOIN `studentattendance` a ON s.`stud_matric`=a.`student_stud_matric`
                        INNER JOIN `course` c ON c.`course_code`=a.`course_course_code`
                        WHERE a.`course_course_code` LIKE 'CTU101'
                        group by a.`student_stud_matric`;";

            $result = $conn->query( $data ) or die ("Error: Something went wrong...");
            if( $result ){

                while( $ser=$result->fetch_object() ) {

                    $per=number_format($ser->sum * 100, 2);

                    echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <center>$counter</center>
                        </td>
                        <td>$ser->stud_matric</td>
                        <td>$ser->stud_name</td>
                        <td>$per</td>
                        <td class='col-medium center'><a href='report.php?stud_matric=$ser->stud_matric'<button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span>View Attendance Report</button></a></td>
                    </tr>";

                    $counter++;
                }
            }
            @mysqli_free_result( $result );
        ?>
        </tbody>
```

`( studatt_endtime - studatt_starttime)` refers to the timeframe for a class is held.
There might be more than one records of the same student that absent to the class (`WHERE studAtt_status= '0'`) (means the student absent for more than one time). I use `SUM` so that I can total up the `( studatt_endtime - studatt_starttime)` that meet to the requirement of the `WHERE studAtt_status= '0'`.

The problem is, it seems to sum up the whole total hour of students absent from every student. Example: Student for matric no 1 have 4 hour of absent hour. So, his absenteeism percentage must be `7.14`.
Whereas student for matric no 2 absent for two hour, so his absenteeism percentage must be `3.57`. As concluded as below: (This is the desired result)

```
NO  MatricNo  Name  Percentage(%)  Action
 1     1      Sara     7.14         Edit
 2     2      Mike     3.57         Edit
```

That is what I want. But What I get from the above code that I've provided is that it sums up the total percentage. This is what I get:

```
NO  MatricNo  Name  Percentage(%)  Action
 1     1      Sara     10.71       Edit
 2     2      Mike     10.71       Edit
```

Below is the details about the attributes contained in every tables affected:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `studentattendance` (
  `studAtt_id` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course_course_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studAtt_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `studAtt_startTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studAtt_endTime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classroom_classroom_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `semester_sem_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_group_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `staff_staff_id` bigint(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `student_stud_matric` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faculty_fac_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `programme_prog_code` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `part_part_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `studAtt_status` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL;
```

...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `stud_matric` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `stud_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stud_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stud_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stud_phone_no` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `faculty_fac_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `programme_prog_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `part_part_id` int(11) NOT NULL;
```

...

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `course` (
  `course_code` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_contacthour` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_credithour` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `course_contactx_perWeek` int(11) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Then, some of samples of INSERTED value:

```
INSERT INTO `studentattendance` (`studAtt_id`, `course_course_code`, `studAtt_date`, `studAtt_startTime`, `studAtt_endTime`, `classroom_classroom_code`, `semester_sem_id`, `group_group_code`, `staff_staff_id`, `student_stud_matric`, `faculty_fac_code`, `programme_prog_code`, `part_part_id`, `studAtt_status`) VALUES
('2013108193CTU1012014-12-30', 'CTU101', '2014-12-30', 14, 16, 'TEC 7', 1, 'KAC110-1B', 1234567890, 2013108193, 'AC', 'AC110', 1, 0);
('2013108193CTU1012014-12-07', 'CTU101', '2014-12-07', 12, 14, 'TEC7', 1, 'KAC110-1B', 1234567890, 2013108193, 'AC', 'AC110', 1, 1);

    INSERT INTO `student` (`stud_matric`, `stud_name`, `stud_address`, `stud_email`, `stud_phone_no`, `faculty_fac_code`, `programme_prog_code`, `part_part_id`) VALUES
    (2013108193, 'sara', '', '', '', 'AC', 'AC110', 1);

    INSERT INTO `course` (`course_code`, `course_name`, `course_contacthour`, `course_credithour`, `course_contactx_perWeek`) VALUES
    ('CTU101', 'FUNDAMENTALS', '2', '2', 2);
```

Let me know if I need to give more information.. TQ

Comment: Can you get rid of all the PHP stuff. It seems irrelevant to this problem

Comment: 100% equal how much?

Comment: I don't know exactly what data you have in your table, but since you're looking for the percentage of each student and don't want the total / summed percentage of all the students, I think you just have to leave out the SUM function.

Comment: Formula: `Percent = 100 * Hours / Total Hours`

Comment: Because i have to get the ( studatt_endtime` - studatt_starttime)` from studentAttendance table, which records all the attendance record.. So, if there is a student has absent two times, there will be two records there. Thats why I need to sum up this ( studatt_endtime` - studatt_starttime)` from the two records. @piscator

Comment: Actually, this whole query is a bit of a mess. Can you instead provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements in support of the desired result.

Comment: I have provide details about the attributes contain in every tables affected in the post @Strawberry

Comment: "Let me know if I need to give more information.. TQ" See above

Comment: Errr what else? @Strawberry

Comment: 1. CREATE statements. Done. 2. INSERT statements. Missing. 3. Desired result corresponding with items 1 & 2. Missing. - Not to mention the irrelevant PHP/html code cluttering up the place!!

Comment: You don't get it. We're trying to replicate your problem, so WE can help YOU. But for us to do that YOU have to help US.